# Application access permission via App Registrations, Users and Groups, Azure Active Directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I setup an application registration via Azure AD -> App Registrations (by following steps on the [link below](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect)) for an ASP.NET MVC app.

Is it possible to restrict access to the app to a group (or Users) created on Azure AD, not all other groups or users on Azure AD?

> Step 2: Register the sample with your Azure Active Directory tenant
>       Sign in to the Azure portal.
>       On the top bar, click on your account and under the Directory list, choose the Active Directory tenant where you wish to register
>   your application.
>       Click on More Services in the left hand nav, and choose Azure Active Directory.
>       Click on App registrations and choose Add.
>       Enter a friendly name for the application, for example 'WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet' and select 'Web Application and/or Web
>   API' as the Application Type. For the sign-on URL, enter the base URL
>   for the sample, which is by default https://localhost:44320/. Click on
>   Create to create the application.
>       While still in the Azure portal, choose your application, click on Settings and choose Properties.
>       Find the Application ID value and copy it to the clipboard.
>       In the same page, change the logoutUrl property to https://localhost:44320/Account/EndSession. This is the default single
>   sign out URL for this sample.
>       For the App ID URI, enter https:///WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet, replacing
>    with the name of your Azure AD tenant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this.

**Solution:**

*Pre: You can use this feature only after you start an Azure AD Premium trial or purchase Azure AD Premium or Azure AD Basic licenses.*

1. You need to Add your Application to the Enterprise Application:

Go to your Azure AD Application > All settings > Required permissions > Grant Permissions > Yes

2. Find your Application in Enterprise Application > Users and groups > Add User > Select one group > Select > Assign

[image]

3. You also need to set the User assignment required to be Yes.

[image]

Your Enterprise Application > Properties > User assignment required > Yes > Save

You can see more details about this feature in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-accessmanagement-group-saasapps).

Comment: You could also add a screenshot of the Properties tab, since you have to set "User assignment required". I could be wrong though :)

Comment: Hi,@juunas Thanks for your reminder. You're right ,we also need to set the User assignment required to be Yes. I'v updated my answer. –

Comment: On step 2, my account does not allow me to use Group. Will it work if ONLY users are added in step 2, rather than group? That is, all users added in step 2 have access, other users have no access.

Comment: @Pingpong .Use the gloabal admin accounts. If your account is a guest account, please set the guest user with no limits in user settings.